# Python, Tkinter Bug (?) - Weird FPS drops when using create_image()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

### Intro:

Github Link: [Here](https://github.com/Adril1n/tkinter_bug)
Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import time
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x100')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg="black")
canvas.place(x=0, y=0, anchor='nw')

root.bind('u', lambda e: switch_use_img())
def switch_use_img():
    global use_image
    use_image = not use_image

use_image = False

clr = "#"+("%06x"%int(np.random.default_rng(42).random()*16777215))
img = Image.new('RGBA', (28, 42), (*bytes.fromhex(clr[1:]), 255))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


def update():
    canvas.delete('all')
    t = time()
    if use_image:
        for _ in range(5000):
            canvas.create_image(50, 50, anchor='c', image=image)
    else:
        for _ in range(5000):
            canvas.create_rectangle(50-14, 50-21, 50+14, 50+21, fill=clr, width=0)
    
    print(f"{'image' if use_image else 'rectangle'}:", (time()-t))
    
    dt = 1000//20 - int((time() - t)*10**3) # 20 : FPS
    print(dt)
    root.after(max(dt, 1), update)

update()
root.mainloop()
```

I think this came up recently in the MacOS 14.3 version. But I'll list some details down below incase they might be relevant.

#### Specs

**Python Version: 3.12.1**

**Conda version: 24.1.2**

**Tkinter version: 8.6.12**

**MacOS: Sonoma 14.3.1 (23D60)**

**Mac: Air M1, 2020 16GB**

Also I believe this was still the issue with python 3.10.13 and Tk Version 8.6.10. This has also been tested on macOS Monterey and with python 3.10.x where it worked as intended; without any FPS drops.

#### Problem / Bug

The weird thing is that the Update time for each loop is actually faster when using create_image() but the overall FPS still drops significantly. The code is a showcase-version of another project so if you have anymore relevant questions please feel free to ask :)

If you recommend that I post this somewhere else, like the cpython-GitHub page, I'd be delighted to know.

#### Update

I messed around a bit more and I think it has to do with the layering of multiple images on top of each other. So when you do create_image() and fill, let's say: (0, 0) -> (50, 50) and then create another image on top of that one. I think, at its core, that's the thing that slows it down.

Actually, I'm not sure anymore Lol. If that were the case I don't see how the longer showcase version is replicating the problem. Because that one doesn't actually create images on top of each other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also want to know why when the time spent inside the for loop drops, the fps also drops. But do keep in mind that creating and deleting a lot of object in a canvas is a bad idea. It's generally better to just update the objects that you have using [`itemconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13212501/11106801) and [`coords`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40772630/11106801)

Comment: @TheLizzard Yeah, that is true. I know tkinter probably isn't the best choice for the larger project (top down game like Pokémon or Caves of Qud) that this is connected to but unfortunately I think itemconfig and all that jazz is difficult to implement. But I also don't want to use PyGame since they are more strict with threading, which is something I'm looking to implement in stuff like the procedural world generation.


Also thank you very much for including the code in the post!